# Is it possible to improve the speed of calculating cryptographic commands like sha256 in U-Boot?

Tags: hardware, u-boot, cryptography

I tried counting `sha256` from the same memory area in U-Boot and on Linux on the same development board (sama5d27-som-ek). The time taken to perform the same operation in U-Boot is almost double. I would like to reduce this time somehow. The sam5d27 microprocessor description mentions a "Hardware Encryption Engine", but there is no detailed description of this module anywhere in the documentation. I tried to add two configs: `SHA_HW_ACCEL` and `SHA_PROG_HW_ACCEL` but if I see correctly, these are configs for NXP processors. What else can I do to speed up the execution of cryptographic operations in U-Boot on my board?

Comment: If linux makes use of the crypto hardware of the processor, but U-Boot doesn't provide the drivers (yet), you can contribute by porting the crypto engine drivers, I guess.